# Drawing a cube in open GL ES1 for the iphone

Tags: iphone, c++, opengl-es, 3d

Hello friendly computer people,

I've been studying openGL with the book [iPhone 3D programming from O'Reilly](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596804831). Below I've posted an example from the text which shows how to draw a cone. I'm still trying to wrap my head around it which is a bit difficult since I'm not super familiar with C++.

Anyway, what I would like to do is draw a cube. Could anyone suggest the best way to replace the following code with one that would **draw a simple cube?**

```
const float coneRadius = 0.5f;
const float coneHeight = 1.866f;
const int coneSlices = 40;

{
    // Allocate space for the cone vertices.
    m_cone.resize((coneSlices + 1) * 2);

    // Initialize the vertices of the triangle strip.
    vector<Vertex>::iterator vertex = m_cone.begin();
    const float dtheta = TwoPi / coneSlices;
    for (float theta = 0; vertex != m_cone.end(); theta += dtheta) {

        // Grayscale gradient
        float brightness = abs(sin(theta));
        vec4 color(brightness, brightness, brightness, 1);

        // Apex vertex
        vertex->Position = vec3(0, 1, 0);
        vertex->Color = color;
        vertex++;

        // Rim vertex
        vertex->Position.x = coneRadius * cos(theta);
        vertex->Position.y = 1 - coneHeight; 
        vertex->Position.z = coneRadius * sin(theta);
        vertex->Color = color;
        vertex++;
    }
}
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is an OpenGL ES 1.1 cube, I created such a sample application (that has texture and lets you rotate it using your finger) that you can grab the code for [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/CubeExample.zip).  I generated this sample for the OpenGL ES session of my course on [iTunes U](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/advanced-iphone-development-spring-2010/id407243032) (I've since fixed the broken texture rendering you see in that class video).

The author is demonstrating how to build a generic 3-D engine in C++ in the book, so his code is a little more involved than mine.  In this part of the code, he's looping through an angle from 0 to 2 * pi in a number of steps corresponding to `coneSlices`.  You could replace his loop with a series of manual vertex additions corresponding to the vertices I have in my sample application in order to draw a cube instead of his cone.  You'd also need to remove the code he has elsewhere for drawing the circular base of the cone.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenGLES 1 you would probably draw a cub using glVertexPointer to submit geometry and glDrawArrays to draw the cube.  See these tutorials:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html

OpenGLES is a C based library.